# Batch file closes when using for /f and if else - reading text in txt files, checking entries

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, text

For the .bat file named "strip_software_v1" that has code below, it exits during one or more of the for loops - indicating a problem (not running as desired).

I need to compare a list of software that is saved in `%computername%-programs.txt` file (I call `file2`) to that in `Software excluded.txt` (`file3`).

When a match is found - ie line in `file3` matches a substring in `file2`, then this is ok, and consider the next one.

For entries that do not match, to append them into `file4` (which is `%computername%-programs-to-check.txt`).

End result would be to end up with `file4` listing any software in `file2` on computer which isn't in `file3`.

The .bat file is called from within another batch file via `call strip_software_v1.bat %file2%`.
Thus the parameter `%1` in the code is `%computername%-programs.txt`.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

REM Echo ##################################################
set "Version_strip_software=v2"
REM Version: %Version_strip_software%
REM Modified 06/01/15 by Nick Prowse
REM Creates "%computername%-programs-to-check.txt" (%file3%), then checks software names in a text file %file2% (in this case %1) 
REM against "software_excluded.txt", and if different appends to "%computername%-programs-to-check"
REM ====================================================

ECHO Running strip_software %Version_strip_software%
REM Path is %1 -- Path of %file2% parsed correctly

rem set "file2=%1"
set "file2=%computername%-programs.txt"
echo File2 is: %file2%

set "file4=%computername%-programs-to-check.txt"
if exist %file4% del %file4%
echo File4 is: %file4%

echo Strip Software %Version_strip_software% >> %file4%
echo Software to check: >> %file4%
echo -------------------- >> %file4%

pause

REM check each entry in 
For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (!file2!) do (
    echo Inside 1st for
    echo Inside 1st for >> %file4%
    pause
    For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%B in (software_excluded.txt) do (
        echo Inside 2nd for
        echo Inside 2nd for >> %file4%
        pause
        IF "%%A"=="%%B" (   
            echo %%A >nul
        ) else (
        echo %%A >> %file4%
        )
    )
)
```

"software_excluded.txt" (file3) currently contains the following:

```
Installed Applications
Adobe Flash
Cisco Jabber
Citrix
Dell KACE Agent
Hotfix for Microsoft
Installed Applications
Microsoft .Net
Security Update for Microsoft
Security Update for Windows
Sophos
Update for Microsoft
Update for Windows
Webfolders XP
```

Some content in %computername%-programs.txt (file2) is below:

```
Installed Applications


Adobe AIR
Version: 13.0

Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client 

Citrix Receiver
Version: 13.1

K-Lite Codec Pack 10.7.5 Basic
```

Output in %computername%-programs-to-check.txt (file4) is below. - Problem is that entries that don't match aren't listed below dashes since the for /f loops cause program to close.

```
Strip Software v2 
Software to check: 
--------------------
```

Please advise

Comment: Please explain that _not running as desired_. However, there is a weird code snippet `IF "%%A"=="%%B" (` not followed with a command; IMHO should be one, at least some no-operation command, e.g. `echo %%A >nul`

Comment: @josefZ Adding `echo %%A >nul` to the code as you described stopped the program from exiting when it shouldn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You've said that `Software excluded.txt` is both file2 and file3 at different points.

Within your loop, you're then reading `software_excluded.txt` (note underscore.)

You've not told us what the output you see is. Your code would apparently check each line within one file against each line in the second, line 1 against lines 1..end, line 2 against line1...end until lastline vs line1...end and display mismatches.

What you would apparently require is

```
findstr /x /i /v /g:"Software?excluded.txt" "%file2%" >"%file3%"
```

That is, find strings in the file "%file2%" which do **not** (/v) exactly match (/x) ignoring case (/i) lines in the file (/g:) "Software?excluded.txt" (i don't know whether you have the underscore there or not) and output the result to `%file3%`.

Comment: I've updated my question to address your points. Thank you for the suggestion of using `findstr`. What would cause the for loops to exit?